# How to ignore clicks for checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to attach a function to a checkbox so that clicking it does nothing. How is this possible? I don't want it to be greyed out, I just want to stop it from being togglable.

Comment: What purpose does it then serve?

Comment: IE has a double-click filter, so to speak, so that double-clicking checkboxes only registers as a single click. This happens to also stop people from toggling checkboxes really fast, which is a feature I need for my application, strangely enough. So I'm just canceling its default functionality and catching clicks by hand with JavaScript/jQuery and toggling it that way, thus eliminating the "speed limit." Except I don't know how to stop the clicks from toggling it in the first place, hence this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want it to be toggleable, just attach an event listener as follows:

```
$('#checkboxId').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note: This is the same effect as returning `false`:

```
$('#checkboxId').on('click', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="this.checked=!this.checked" />
```

Comment: 7 years later and this solved it for me. thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){return false;});
```

just return false on click event,
working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Sh8Zu/

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 <input type="checkbox" onChange="return checkChange(this)" id="checkid"/>
function checkChange(obj)
  {

 obj.checked=false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want but this disables the checkbox using JQuery.

```
$('#checkboxId').attr('disabled', true);
```

For a non-grey out [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/nKwRj/):

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() { return false; });
```

Comment: i think he wants the click(function(){return false}.. making it disabled will grey it out