# Why is jQuery .prop not working, seemingly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

[Sql Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fPnm3/1/)

```
$('#myBox').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('#myBox').prop("checked", !$('#myBox').prop("checked") );
});
```

I'm attaching this to a checkbox so that the check toggling is controlled by my javascript instead of by the default behavior, and it *just won't work.* I can't figure out why!

*My reason for doing this*: IE has a double-click filter, so to speak, so that double-clicking checkboxes only registers as a single click. This happens to stop people from toggling checkboxes really fast, which is a feature I need for my application, strangely enough. So I'm just canceling its default functionality and catching clicks by hand with JavaScript/jQuery and toggling it that way, thus eliminating the "speed limit." Except I don't know how to stop the clicks from toggling it in the first place, hence this question.

Comment: Why are you preventing the default action **and** toggling it yourself?

Comment: See comments under this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578792/how-to-ignore-clicks-for-checkboxes

Comment: Ok. In that case, you might want to toggle that checkbox from some other element, which would be more practical for your example.

Comment: If you explain the issue you're facing, you will possibly get better answers. For example, if you're preventing the default action just so you can perform your own validation before toggling, you can instead add the validation check and in case it fails call preventDefault.

Comment: Did you follow that link and read what I wrote there? I merely want to toggle really, really fast. That's all.

Comment: Oh the double click issue. Firefox also has it. I've posted a plugin to fix that for Firefox sometime ago but as for IE, the old IE's event model lacks too many events for the second click of a double click to be "fixed" consistently. Honestly, I believe that a good part of old IE users probably can't differentiate what should be double clicked or not and may double click checkboxes, in that case I'd leave them to the behavior they are used to.

Comment: (I completely agree. This has long since just become a personal challenge to get this working.)

Comment: @ErikE It no longer does. I believe that was fixed in IE9 or 10.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté oops I deleted my comment, deciding it was a bit over the top.

Comment: @ErikE Yeah I saw that, no problem. `:P` But I agree with the deleted comment. People should learn how to use the interfaces properly instead of being spoon-fed. Of course this is no excuse to don't provide a good UI, but rather, provide a good one assuming that people have basic UI use knowledge.

Comment: Yeah. Honestly when I saw this in the bug queue ("checkbox requires double-clicking in IE...") I should have just said, no, that's a feature of IE, not something we did wrong, but then I just decided to go and fix it anyway, because I  hate that mentality so much, of spoon-feeding people so they don't have to learn.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté One reason I hate the spoon-feeding (a.k.a "hand-holding") so much is that it interferes with what I want to do as an expert user--exactly like Aerovistae is finding, here. I *hate* it when MS Word selects whole words instead of respecting my selection points, or selects the space after a word, or the paragraph mark, or does about a dozen other stupid things that *I do not want it to do*. Or when Word/Excel convert my pasted HTML into rendered HTML... ARGH! The "hand-holding" becomes "magic evil meddling."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myBox').prop("checked", !$('#myBox').prop("checked") );
}, 1);
```

The delayed timer of 1 millisecond is all it takes.

See this in [your jsFiddle, modified](http://jsfiddle.net/fPnm3/4/).

Comment: Why on EARTH does that fix the problem?

Comment: The *why* is a completely different question. Try searching here.

Comment: @Aero Because it inserts the action into the "queue" of asynchronous events waiting to happen and allows the current function to exit scope. Basically, the `click` event processing code has to exit before you are free to change the property... though *why*, well, I also am not sure.

Comment: @BradM I'll accept your answer since it happens to be right, but for the record, telling people to "go search for their problems" when they ask for more understanding of an answer is asinine. I have a thousand rep, not 5, I know how to use search, and I DID use search, and it didn't tell me what I needed this time. So again, thanks for nothing. Lots of thanks to ErikE, whose explanation gave me the insight to fix the whole problem, all of which is not posted here.

Comment: Thanks for nothing? Lol guy, I *solved* your problem. You can't expect a full-fledged ultra detailed response for every question you ask. I have no idea why it works, hence why I suggested searching for it here.

Comment: I was under the impression you were saying it wasn't worth your time to explain your answer; what you said could be read two ways. In that case I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to run something when your checkbox changes...

In that case you should be catching the change event:

```
$('#myBox').bind('change', function() {
    // Do checks here, if you don't want it to change, then deal with it then
});
```